# Proper term for a variable whose value affects the output of another variable?

Tags: logic

Assume a given variable, $x$, has a value that is a function of a set of variables, $a, b, c$.

$a, b,$ and $c$ can be said to be the independent variables. However often times in modelling real life scenarios, $a, b,$ and $c$ will have values dependent on another "layer" of variables, and those variables will be dependent on yet another deeper layer.

In the context of this perspective, is there any proper or common term used for these variables instead of "dependent" and "independent", that does more to denote the hierarchical nature of this chain of variable dependencies?

For lack of a better term i have just been saying "subvariables" but would like to know if I am missing a better term.

Comment: In a general hierarchy there will not be special terminology that avoids the need to articulate a "chain of variable dependencies".  A variety of terms are used for the simple case that $x$ is a function (dependent variable) of independent variables $a,b,c$.  I can suggest some of the alternative terms for dependent vs. independent variables, but if you have a model with many layers, it will be just as complex to explain using alternative terminology.

Comment: Is "parameter" the term you're looking for? A parameter is a variable that affects another.